# Why can't I detect this Exception in my Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am writing an Intigration test using nUnit in C#.

My code is:

```
public async Task<bool> WriteData(Document data, string tableName)
{
   try
   {
      var table = Table.LoadTable(_dynamoDbClient, tableName);
      table.PutItem(data);
      return true;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
     _logger.Info("Failed Writing Record");
     _logger.Info("Error: " + e.Message);
     return false;
   }
}
```

My Test is:

```
public void TestToSeeIfWeGetAnExceptionWhenProvidingBadDataToTheDatabase()
{
   // arrange
   var item = new Document
   {
      ["Id"] = "1001",
      ["TransactionID"] = 111111,
      ["StatementType"] = "TestBank"
   };

   _bankStatementTable = "does-not-exist";

   // act / assert

   Assert.Catch<System.Exception>(() => _awsDynamoDbManager.WriteData(item, _bankStatementTable));
}
```

Because I am passing bad data to the database I expect an exception and I get one.
However, the test fails.
I get this message from the test runner:

> Expected: instance of <System.Exception>
>
> But was:  null

If I run the test in Debug I can see the Catch being hit.
What am I missing?

Comment: I think `Assert.Catch` only works for uncought exceptions.

Comment: `WriteData` returns `false` in case of exception

Comment: You are consuming the exception within the subject under test. There is nothing to catch in the test itself. You need to assert the expected behavior for that test case, which is that the subject will return **`false`** if an exception is thrown

Answer (score 2):

You should update your code a little bit. Rethrow an `Exception` in `catch` block and use [`ThrowsAsync`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.ThrowsAsync)

```cs
catch (Exception e)
{
     _logger.Info("Failed Writing Record");
     _logger.Info("Error: " + e.Message);
     throw;
}
...
Assert.ThrowsAsync<System.Exception>(async () => await _awsDynamoDbManager.WriteData(item, _bankStatementTable));
```

Or check that `WriteData` returns `false` by making test as `async` as well and call `Assert.IsFalse`

```cs
public async Task TestToSeeIfWeGetAnExceptionWhenProvidingBadDataToTheDatabase()
{
   // arrange
   ...
   // act / assert

   var result = await _awsDynamoDbManager.WriteData(item, _bankStatementTable);
   Assert.IsFalse(result);
}
```

Since there is no awaitable code inside `WriteData` method, you can make it synchronous one and use `Task.FromResult` as return result or make it even simpler and remove using of `Task<bool>`

```cs
public bool WriteData(Document data, string tableName)
{
   try
   {
      var table = Table.LoadTable(_dynamoDbClient, tableName);
      table.PutItem(data);
      return true;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
     _logger.Info("Failed Writing Record");
     _logger.Info("Error: " + e.Message);
     return false; //or throw;
   }
}
```

And the synchronous test code

```cs
Assert.Throws<System.Exception>(() => _awsDynamoDbManager.WriteData(item, _bankStatementTable));
```

or

```cs
public void TestToSeeIfWeGetAnExceptionWhenProvidingBadDataToTheDatabase()
{
   // arrange
   ...
   // act / assert

   var result = _awsDynamoDbManager.WriteData(item, _bankStatementTable);
   Assert.IsFalse(result);
}
```

Comment: Should also mention about the fact that the method under test is not actually async, since nothing is awaited. They could wrap the intensive stuff in a `Task.Run` or remov `async` and return `Task.FromResult(true/false)`

Comment: @Richard210363 Does it answer your question, do you need more information or details?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are returning false in case of Exception:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    _logger.Info("Failed Writing Record");
    _logger.Info("Error: " + e.Message);
    return false;
}
```

Use `throw` clause.

Comment: Returning True or False makes no difference to the Test result.  I still get "null"